# Mac OS X, Vagrant, Docker, Nginx, Node - how do ports play together?

Tags: node.js, nginx, vagrant, docker, vagrantfile

I have a simple nginx, node.js setup that I want to migrate into the Vagrant, Docker world. I'm not sure how to handle IPs and ports.

My goal is it to see my `Hello World` in the Browser, best case on port 80, simply by calling my host `http://example.com`.

**UPDATE**
I found the solution myself - I created a simple boilerplate here:
https://github.com/ezmilhouse/docker
Feel free to go on from here.

**app.js**

```
var app = express();

app.route('*').all(function(req, res) {
  res.send('Hello World!');
});

app.listen(2000)
```

**nginx.conf**

```
upstream example.com {

  # using the vagrant private network IP (I guess?)
  # using the node port
  server 192.168.33.10:2000

}

server {

  # ports nginx server is listen to
  listen 80;
  listen 443;

  location / {

    # upstream proxy
    proxy_pass http://example.com;

    # ...

  }

}
```

**Vagrantfile.proxy**

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
  config.vm.provision "docker"

  # settimg a hostname that matches nginx upstream (I guess?)
  config.vm.hostname = "example.com"

  # setting a private network IP, node.js and nginx run on this IP (i guess?)
  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10"

end
```

**Vagrantfile**

```
  Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

    config.vm.define "nginx" do |app|
      # forward the nginx port (I guess?)
      app.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 80
      app.vm.provider "docker" do |d|
        d.build_dir  = "./docker/nginx"
        d.vagrant_vagrantfile = "./Vagrantfile.proxy"
      end
    end

    config.vm.define "node" do |app|
      # forward the node port (I guess?)
      app.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 2000, host: 2000
      app.vm.provider "docker" do |d|
        d.build_dir  = "./docker/node"
        d.vagrant_vagrantfile = "./Vagrantfile.proxy"
      end
    end

  end
```

**/nginx/Dockerfile**

```
# ...
EXPOSE ["80"]
```

**/node/Dockerfile**

```
# ...
EXPOSE ["2000"]
```

**Mac OS X /etc/hosts**

```
192.168.33.10 example.com
```

I was expecting to call `http://192.168.33.10` in the browser to see my `Hello World` via nginx and `http://192.168.33.10:2000` to see the node instance. Therefore the host `example.com` does not work either.

What do I do wrong?

Comment: Could you try EXPOSE N rather than EXPOSE ["N"]?

Comment: Can you share a link to github repo with you code? It's interesting to play with it a little bit

Comment: @kharandziuk - github repo here: https://github.com/ezmilhouse/docker

Comment: @seanmcl turns aout that you don't have to expose the ports at all (at least in a Vagrant setting)

Comment: I've created a demo project with a nginx-nodejs setup. See if you can get any inspiration from that: https://github.com/materik/docker-web-backend-frontend-demo

Answer (score 0):

I created the [fork](https://github.com/kharandziuk/docker) and made [pull request](https://github.com/ezmilhouse/docker-station/pull/1) to your repo.

The main idea: do not use provisioning for docker containers.

More information your can find in this [article](https://blog.abevoelker.com/rails-development-using-docker-and-vagrant/)